# Laravel 4.1, White Blank Screen When using Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel-4

I'm newbie in using Laravel & need the help. Why the white blank white screen appears in my web browser when i want using eloquent. The code in the below(Sorry for long post, i want make that clear):

UserController.php(Controller)

```
<?php
class UserController extends \BaseController {

/**
 * Display a listing of the resource.
 *
 * @return Response
 */
public function index() //GET
{
    //
    $users = User::all();
    //$users->toarray();
    return View::make('users.index', compact('users'));
}

/**
 * Show the form for creating a new resource.
 *
 * @return Response
 */
public function create()//GET
{
    //

}

/**
 * Store a newly created resource in storage.
 *
 * @return Response
 */
public function store()//POST
{
    //
}

/**
 * Display the specified resource.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return Response
 */
public function show($id)//GET
{
    //
}

/**
 * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return Response
 */
public function edit($id)//GET
{
    //
}

/**
 * Update the specified resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return Response
 */
public function update($id)//PUT
{
    //
}

/**
 * Remove the specified resource from storage.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return Response
 */
public function destroy($id)//DELETE
{
    //
}

}
```

User.php(Model)

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableInterface;

class User extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {

/**
 * The database table used by the model.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $table = 'users';

/**
 * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $hidden = array('password');

/**
 * Get the unique identifier for the user.
 *
 * @return mixed
 */

public function getRememberToken()
{
    return $this->remember_token;
}

public function setRememberToken($value)
{
    $this->remember_token = $value;
}

public function getRememberTokenName()
{
    return 'remember_token';
}

public function getAuthIdentifier()
{
    return $this->getKey();
}

/**
 * Get the password for the user.
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getAuthPassword()
{
    return $this->password;
}

/**
 * Get the e-mail address where password reminders are sent.
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getReminderEmail()
{
    return $this->email;
}
}
```

Index.blade.php(View)

```
@section('main')

<h1>All Users</h1>

<p>{{ link_to_route('users.create', 'Add new user') }}</p>

@if ($users->count())
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
    <thead>
    <tr>
    <th>Username</th>
    <th>Password</th>
    <th>Email</th>
    <th>Phone</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        @foreach ($users as $user)
            <tr>
                <td>{{ $user->username }}</td>
      <td>{{ $user->password }}</td>
      <td>{{ $user->email }}</td>
      <td>{{ $user->phone }}</td>
      <td>{{ $user->name }}</td>
                <td>{{ link_to_route('users.edit', 'Edit',
     array($user->id), array('class' => 'btn btn-info')) }}</td>
                <td>
      {{ Form::open(array('method' 
      => 'DELETE', 'route' => array('users.destroy', $user->id))) }}                       
                        {{ Form::submit('Delete', array('class'
      => 'btn btn-danger')) }}
                    {{ Form::close() }}
                </td>
            </tr>
        @endforeach

    </tbody>

</table>
@else
There are no users
@endif

@stop
```

Comment: Do you have debug mode set to true?

Comment: @JSelser of course i have been set to true

Comment: Try changing the las `@stop` for a `@show`

Comment: @JSelser it's works! after changed it to show .Thanks Mr, but please can you explain it?

Comment: Sure, I'll post an answer

Comment: @RyanVincent: so where i could implementing it,  if i want using die('i am here: '. __FILE__.__LINE__);? in first line  of Model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you define sections you can tell blade how and when to display them, you do that with the closing directives like `@stop`, `@show`, `@overwrite` etc.

`@stop` means you define a section for later use(meaning it **doesn't show**) so it can be used or be overriden later by another. To use a stored section you can use `@yield('sectionName')`.

So if you had a general layout you want in every page, say, like a footer, you could keep reusing it with `@extends('view')` by replacing certain parts:

```
{{--this is layout.blade.php--}}

@yield('content')

<div>My awesome footer</div>
```

And you'd make separate views like so:

```
{{--this is contact.blade.php--}}

@extends('layout')

@section('content')
  <div>Contact me: someMail@dem.mails</div>
@stop
```

`@yield` would be in charge of "yielding" (showing) your section. The idea is that you can decide **what sections contain** and **where are shown** at **different moments**.

What if you wanted to `@yield` the section you just defined? That's what `@show` is for.

[Here](http://daylerees.com/codebright/blade) is a link to an awesome online book chapter about laravel's blade templating which I find more friendly and in-depth than the official documentation. Have fun and code wild.

Comment: Thanks so much Mr! Also awesome link reference

Comment: Mr, please help my next question about templating: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30656072/laravel-4-1-folder-layouts-not-available-in-views-folder

i had tried to figure out about templating using layouts schema but something wrong